# Fetch No oF Rows that can be returned by select query

Tags: sql, postgresql, jdbc

I'm trying to fetch data and showing in a table with pagination. so I use limit and offset for that but I also need to show no of rows that can be fetched from that query. Is there any way to get that.
I tried

```
resultset.last() and getRow()
select count(*) from(query) myNewTable;
```

These two cases i'm getting correct answer but is it correct way to do this. Performance is a concern

Comment: I suggest not to care about this. It can be potentially expensive to determine how many results there will be in total. Instead, just fetch 1 more row than you show and you will know that there will be at least one more page.

Answer (score 0):

We can get the limited records using below code,

First, we need to set how many records we want like below,

```
var limit = 10;
```

After that sent this limit to the below statement

```
WITH
    Temp AS(
        SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER( primayKey DESC ) AS RowNumber,
            *
        FROM
            myNewTable
    ),
    Temp2 AS(
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS TotalCount FROM Temp
    )
SELECT TOP limit * FROM Temp, Temp2 WHERE RowNumber > :offset order by RowNumber
```

This is run in both MSSQL and MySQL

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way of doing this.

**1.** As you found out, it usually boils down to executing 2 queries:

Executing `SELECT` with limit and offset in order to fetch the data that you need.

Executing a `COUNT(*)` in order to count the total number of pages.

This approach might work for tables that don't have a lot of rows, or when you filter the data (int the `COUNT` and `SELECT` queries) on a column that is indexed.

**2.** If your table is large, but the data that you need to show represents smaller percentage of the data from the table **and** the data shares a common trait (for example, the data in all of your pages is created on a single day) you can use [partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/ddl-partitioning.html). Executing `COUNT` and `SELECT` on a single partition will be way more faster than executing them on the whole table.

**3.** You can create another table which will store the value of the `COUNT` query.
For example, lets say that your **big_table** table looks like this:

```
id | user_id | timestamp_column | text_column | another_text_column
```

Now, your `SELECT` query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM big_table WHERE user_id = 4 ORDER BY timestamp_column LIMIT 20 OFFSET 20;
```

And your count query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE user_id = 4;
```

You could create a **count_table** that will have the following format:

```
user_id | count
```

Once you fill this table with the current data in the system, you will create a trigger which will update this table on every insert or update of the **big_table**.

This way, the count query will be really fast, because it will be executed on the **count_table**, for example:

```
SELECT count FROM count_table WHERE user_id = 4
```

The drawback of this approach is that the insert in the **big_table** will be slower, since the trigger will fire and update the *count_table* on every insert.

This are the approaches that you can try but in the end it all depends on the size and type of your data.